# How to debug an erroneous call stack in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, dynamic-dispatch

I am working with a huge class from a 3rd-Pary library, here is an excerpt of relevant stuff:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    virtual int SetTableSize(unsigned int uiTableID, int iSize);
    // ...
protected:
    // ...
    virtual int Set_0xB0_0x23_IsoTableData(unsigned char* ucData, int iLen);
    // ...
};
```

My application breaks with a memory access violation. The uppermost item in the call stack is a code line in the implementation of `Set_0xB0_0x23_IsoTableData`, the second item is a code line like this:

```
someClassInstance.SetTableSize(2, 400);
```

In debug view, `ucData` has the value `0x00000002`, so it really looks like instead of calling the implementation of `SetTableSize`, which should happen according to the code, `Set_0xB0_0x23_IsoTableData` gets called with the parameters specified - which obviously leads to an error, because the pointer isn't valid.

I have already spent much time figuring out what happens here. I compile the same code inside a different application with GCC on Linux, and it works there. Is this a Visual Studio compiler bug? I don't get any warning when I compile this code.

It's not possible to construct a minimal working example to reproduce the bug - at least not until I figure out the reason why this happens. The `SomeClass` header does have quite some `#ifdef`s in it, so the first thing I thought was that preprocessor defines were different when compiling the module containing `SomeClass` than when compiling my calling code. However, I double-checked and the definitions are the same.

So what I want to ask is basically:

- Under what conditions can a call to a virtual method invoke the implementation of another virtual method? (this is not about inheritance - the two methods are defined in the same class and do not even share their signature and have different visibility)
- How can I debug such an error? Is it possible to view the dispatch vector of the class instance in Visual Studio?

Comment: You may have broken your stack, for instance by writing past the end of a buffer, or by using stale pointers. This may have happened far away from the code you're seeing on the stack, unfortunately.

Comment: This is a pretty common module boundary problem.  The code that makes the call was built with an incompatible view of the class.  Could be that you use a static library that was built with a different version of the compiler or standard C++ library.  Could be a DLL Hell problem.  Could be as simple as mixing debug and release builds.  Your question excludes none of these kind of mishaps.  Rebuild everything with the exact same settings.

Comment: @HansPassant I already compile the 3rd-Party library from source as part of my solution, and the solution is created by CMake, which ensures that defines are the same.

Answer (score 0):

My standard answer for those kind of problems: Rebuild all. In some cases it is as simple / stupid as that (at least for Visual Studio).

If the error still remains, then what I'd do is debugging: Run the code as far as you can say "it cannot have happened by now". Then debug step by step, line by line and watch the call stack closely.

And no, this is not fun.

Comment: I already rebuild everything multiple times. Step-by-step-debugging only shows what I already know: That the method call invokes the wrong method. All variable values seem to be okay the whole time. I don't know what else to look for.